# Add DependencyObject to control from code-behind

Tags: silverlight

I want to add a DependencyObject to a control from code behind.  I have searched and searched online for how to do this with absolutely no success.  The DependencyObject has a DependencyProperty.  I also want to set this property from code-behind.

charting:ChartBehaviors inherits directly from DependencyObject. It is a class I wrote myself.  The Chart control is a Third-party control.

charting:ChartBehaviors.FloatingTooltip is the DependencyProperty.  This is also a class I wrote myself.

Here is what it looks like in XAML.  I want to do this in code behind so that I can turn on and off the "behavior".

```
<charting:Chart>
   <charting:ChartBehaviors.FloatingTooltip>
      <charting:FloatingTooltipBehavior
         TooltipTemplate="{StaticResource tooltipTemplate}" />
  </charting:ChartBehaviors.FloatingTooltip>
</charting:Chart>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use the SetValue method on the object (assuming you give your chart an id of chart1).

```
var behave = new FloatingTooltipBehavior();
chart1.SetValue(ChartBehaviors.FloatingTooltipProperty, behave);
```

Another solution would be to just add an Enabled property to your behavior and then set that from the code behind.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you basically instantiate necessary dependency object and use appropriate method to add it to the control. For example, to add TextBlock to the StackPanel, you write it like this:

```
TextBlock txtMyText = new TextBlock();
stackPanel.Children.Add(txtMyText);
```

If you're wanting to add certain behavior to a chart, you should just get your chart object in code and look for a property like Behaviors or something. Then you either assign a behavior (if it's one-behavior-only) or add it like to the stackpanel:

```
Chart myChart;
myChart.Behavior = new FloatingTooltipBehavior();
```

It's hard to tell the exact syntax without knowing the component.

Comment: Chart is a third-party control and there is no such mechanism in the class for adding DependencyObjects. It is just a custom DependencyObject. See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyobject(v=vs.95).aspx